# Discord ID & Channel list to Google Sheets - Efficiency

Tags: python, google-sheets, discord.py, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a small code I made.  I am absolutely sure it is fairly ineffecient, but I am trying to learn how to do things better.  What methods would you suggest to improve upon this?  Namely, not needing the sleep portion or hitting a warning every time it loops.

```
    for text_channel in ctx.message.guild.text_channels:
        x = len(sheetsChannelList.get_all_values()) + 1
        sheetsChannelList.update_cell(x,2, text_channel.name)
        sheetsChannelList.update_cell(x,3, text_channel.id)
        time.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question and showing script, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to append the values of `text_channel.name` and `text_channel.id` from column "B" of `sheetsChannelList` sheet.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
ar = []
for text_channel in obj:
    ar.append([text_channel.name, text_channel.id])
x = len(sheetsChannelList.get_all_values()) + 1
sheetsChannelList.update("B" + str(x), ar, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- By this modification, the values of `text_channel.name, text_channel.id` are put into an array and the array is appended from column "B" of Spreadsheet.

Comment: I could be completely misunderstanding how your code works.  

My understanding is that would take values from column "B" of the Spreadsheet rather than putting information to column "B" and "C".

Comment: @Xiael Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `I could be completely misunderstanding how your code works. My understanding is that would take values from column "B" of the Spreadsheet rather than putting information to column "B" and "C".`, when I saw your showing script, it seems that the values of `text_channel.name, text_channel.id` are appended to columns "B" and "C".

Comment: @Xiael But, you say `My understanding is that would take values from column "B" of the Spreadsheet rather than putting information to column "B" and "C".`. And also, in your question, you say `What methods would you suggest to improve upon this?`. From this situation, I'm confusing your goal for this question. So, can I ask you about the detail of your actual expected result? I would like to correctly understand your actual expected result. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Xiael About `My understanding is that would take values from column "B" of the Spreadsheet rather than putting information to column "B" and "C".`, do you want to append values `text_channel.name, text_channel.id` from column "B"? Or, do you want to retrieve values from columns "B" and "C"? From your question and showing script, I thought that the former is your expected result. My answer is for this. Is my understanding correct?